# Attahment inside a form - odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How can we add an attachment to upload file and **to be like a simple field inside the odoo form**

PS : i don't want the attachment to be on the Top of the from i want it just like the way we add fields in odoo.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try `fields.Binary`

Ex:

```
data_file = fields.Binary(string='File')
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 attachment_ids = fields.Many2many('ir.attachment', 'attachment_id',string='Attachments')
```